# Enforce someone to use only factory for creating objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I have a `Shape` interface and having `Circle` and `Triangle` classes which implements `Shape` interface. Lets say method is `printShape()` which just print type of shape.

Now there is one factory class ie `ShapeFactory` based on factory design pattern which provides `Circle` and `Triangle` objects.

Now i want to enforce everyone to use `ShapeFactory` for creating objects of `Circle` and `Triangle`.

May be if someone not aware about `ShapeFactory` exist then he/she can create object with `new` without using `Shapefacoty`. I want No one should create an object like `Shape shape = new Circle`.

How do I do that?

Comment: you could set the constructor of Circle and Triangle to private

Comment: It won't help. Even Factory won't be able to create objects.

Comment: Since `Circle` and `Triangle` are `interface`s, they can't be constructed.  If your API does not provide any publicly available implementations, then a user will not be able to create any instance, unless, they implement the `interface`s themselves, which you can't stop. If the classes are used internally to your API, you could use `instanceof` to check that the instance been passed to your API is one of your implementations and reject all others :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Sir, Circle and Triangle are classes which implements Shape interface.

Comment: what about something like this? `public class Triangle {
    public static Triangle unsafelyCreateInstance() {
        return new Triangle();
    }
    private Triangle() { }
}`

Comment: @VJS: If `Circle` is an abstract class, nobody can produce its instances directly either. (But most often a factory should produce instances conforming to an interface, not a specific implementation.)

Comment: @9000 : Then even how factory will create an object of `Circle`?

Comment: Can we do something using static inner class ?

Comment: @VJS Yes, a static inner class is possible. I updated my answer to include exactly that. Consider accepting my answer if it solves your problem exactly the way you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't want anyone to be able to use a class, **other than the classes in your own package**, then simply make those classes *package-private*.

**IF** you want to prohibit classes from even the same package as ShapeFactory to use the classes that implement the `Shape` interface, then skip the first example and go to the example below the *UPDATE* quote.

Have a look at the example below, that showcases the usage of packages.

```
package Shapes;

class Circle implements Shape{
//implementation
}
```

---

```
package Shapes; 

class Triangle implements Shape{
//implementation
}
```

---

```
package Shapes;

public class ShapeFactory{

  public static Triangle createTriangle(){
    return new Triangle();
  }

  public static Circle createCircle(){
    return new Circle();
  }
}
```

---

```
package SomeOtherPackage;
import Shapes.ShapeFactory;

public class OtherClass{
  Shape myCircle = ShapeFactory.createCircle();
  Shape myTriangle = ShapeFactory.createTriangle();
}
```

Finally, as for the *What if the users don't know that ShapeFactory exists?* question.
That is why documentation exists. To let other programmers, using your API, know how to use it!

> **UPDATE**
>
> Even though the above methodology is correct and will provide the functionality that is asked, the below paradigm will demonstrate how to **prevent** other classes (even from within the same package) to be able to use classes that implement the `Shape` interface. They will only be able to create other shapes via `ShapeFactory()`.

```
//ShapeFactory can be public, or package-private. Depends on programmer's needs
public class ShapeFactory {

    //If factory methods are static, then inner classes need to be static too!
    public static Circle createCircle(){
        return new Circle();
    }

    public static Triangle createTriangle(){
        return new Triangle();
    }


    /*Inner classes must  be set to private, to mask their existance
     from all other classes, except ShapeFactory. Static is only needed
     if the factory method that produces an instance of said class, is
     going to be static itself.*/
    static private class Circle implements Shape{
        private Circle(){
            //Circle implementation
        }
    }

    static private class Triangle implements Shape{
        private Triangle(){
            //triangle implementation
        }
    }

    //More inner classes, etc..

}
```

> After `ShapeFactory` is created as above, Shapes can be instantiated from any class of any other package, *(even from the same package as `ShapeFactory`)*, **ONLY** via `ShapeFactory`.

```
//An arbitrary class that can belong to any package
public class ArbitraryClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        //creation of Shapes using ShapeFactory
        Shape myCircle = ShapeFactory.createCircle();
        Shape myTriangle = ShapeFactory.createTriangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not very helpful. How many of us read documentation just for creating an object? What if someone has not followed documentation and mistakenly created an object? and even our code is allowing someone to create an object with new operator.

Comment: Mistakenly created an object? It seems that you don't really understand how access levels work in java (private, public, protected). Also, it seems that you didn't really read the part about packages, that I wrote about. Have a look [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for the official documentation about access levels. I suggest you read through it. It will help you understand why the above solution works. Nobody outside the `Shapes` package can access `Circle()` or `Triangle()`.

Comment: Looks like you didn't understand my point. Within the same package, it's accessible.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
    // this class is in package scope, nobody can access it outside this package
class ShapeImpl1 implements Shape {

        // default is package scope
        ShapeImpl1() {
        }

        @Override
        public void print() {

        }
    }

    public class ShapeFactory {


        public Shape buildShape() {
            return new ShapeImpl1();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but other classes from the same package would create ShapeImpl1 object with new operator. Ex : Shape shape = new ShapeImpl1();

Comment: @VJS the reason why use package scope is encapsulation, you should not put a client in same package

Comment: Someone needs to use ShapeImpl1 object in the same package and mistakenly he created it through new operator as the code is not stopping it considering the fact that he is not aware about ShapeFactory.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct and does exactly what you asked. Look at the comment above ShapeImpl1 class. 宏杰李 clearly explains it.
I tried to make myself clearer in my answer. Have a look at my comment below, I left a very helpful guide for access-control. Hope it helps

Comment: @Sotzikevich, but nobody prevents other programmer to create a package with exactly same name as a package with `ShapeImpl1` in his own project or create a new class at the same package and be able to create instances of `ShapeImpl1` with `new`. Technically constructor should be `private` and each concrete class should have a `static` method which will return new instance of that class.

Comment: @lvan you can never put your source code in the same package of `java.util`. so, if you do not want other people to put this source code to your package, just make them depend on your binary build, like jar file.

Comment: @Ivan See my answer for this question. At classes `Circle()` and `Triangle()`, I don't provide any implementation; I have that commented out. It's up to the user to do that, but what you're saying, is the same as having a public constructor and it's not at all a factory. The classes should be package-private. 宏杰李 and I provide the same solution, which is the correct approach for this problem. Also, look at the above comment, it explains it simply.